# Login email and password dropbox account using sharpbox 1.2 API

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, dropbox, sharpbox

My question is, how can I login in my *Dropbox* windows phone 8 project with email and password?

I am using sharpbox 1.2 API.
I want that other user can access their dropbox account by my application.

Answer (score 0):

The only authentication scheme supported by the Dropbox API is OAuth. There's no way to programmatically access an account using a username and password.

Comment: Thanks for comment can you halp me to use OAuth.

Comment: If you have a specific question about OAuth, please start a new question and show us the code you've written so far.